# How to create buttons that increment and decrements values in PHP Codeinginter?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

for a field Balance I want to create two buttons Add and Minus Buttons. This Field shows the current balance of Reseller. So now instead to adding some values in the text box i want to add buttons to its side so that i can increment the values in that field. Also i want to add the incremented value to existing(old) value. i know there are many example over the net but didn't worked for me so please help me.

My Balance Field :

```
    <tr>
            <td>Balance</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('balance', set_value('balance', $user->balance)); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

The Increment Decrement Buttons :
[image: The Current Status]

```
<link href="<?php echo site_url('css/bootstrap.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/add.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/datepicker.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">





            <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/jquery-ui.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/jquery-ui.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/jquery-ui.structure.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/jquery-ui.theme.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="<?php echo site_url('css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">



            <link href="<?php echo site_url('/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

            <link href="<?php echo site_url('/dist/css/timeline.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

            <link href="<?php echo site_url('/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

            <link href="<?php echo site_url('/bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

            <link href="<?php echo site_url('bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

            <link href="<?php echo site_url('bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

            <link href="<?php echo site_url('bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

            <link href="<?php echo site_url('bower_components/datatables-responsive/css/dataTables.responsive.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

            <link href="<?php echo site_url('/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">


            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo site_url('img/favicon.ico'); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />


            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>




                        <script>
                        $(function()
                        {
                            $('#spinnerInput').spinner();
                        });
                        </script>








            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



        <script src="<?php echo site_url('js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo site_url('css/external/jquery/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo site_url('bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo site_url('/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo site_url('/bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo site_url('/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js'); ?>"></script>






            <script src="<?php echo site_url('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>

            <script src="<?php echo site_url('bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js');?>"></script>


            <script src="<?php echo site_url('bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js');?>"></script>

            <script src="<?php echo site_url('js/morris-data.js');?>"></script>

            <script src="<?php echo site_url('dist/js/sb-admin-2.js');?>"></script> 




          <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
                        responsive: true
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: have you tried jquery [spinner](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/)?

Comment: Yeah but didn't understood how to implement it. as i copy pasted the whole code  but maybe due to css i could'nt get the increment decrement buttons

Comment: can you please post what have you tried so far. Please post jsfiddle link if you can.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Hi please check the updated question. i have added an image. I tried with spinner and have succeeded to do this! And it working fine as i need the issue in now only with design as the arrows are looking odd

Comment: inspect this jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/78xxjvde/4/. Can you recreate your problem by editing this jsfiddle link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Rajan1992/78xxjvde/5/ i have edited the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88346/discussion-between-rajan-and-bhushan-kawadkar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add jquery-ui js and css files along with required images. Please download the files and images from below urls

JS - http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js 
CSS - http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css 
images -

https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png 
         https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png

Comment: Hey don't know why but now i am getting this error :Uncaught TypeError: $(...).spinner is not a function

Comment: check if jquery-ui.js properly included and jquery.js must be there before this file.

Comment: Yes I have!  See the updated question code. the Link is working fine

Comment: you are using `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js` which might getting blocked to download which happens inconsistently. Better save this file at your local and give path in your html file instead of using this web url. Do same for jquery-ui.js also.

Comment: It's working after i removed Jquery.js file from the header php file

Comment: Okay i will do that as well :)